# Sorting rows of table permanently in a SQL Server CE database

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a database which has a table named `dictionary` and it has 2 columns named `english` and `bangla`. The table contains about 70,000 rows. I want to sort the data according to `english` column alphabetically.

I know how can sort them in a SQL query:

```
SELECT english, bangla
FROM dictionary
ORDER BY english
```

But it just shows as I queried. It doesn't effect permanently on database.

What I want is to sort the database permanently.

How can I do that???

Another question:

I have about 70,000 rows and when I perform a search query in my windows app the searching result is very slow. If I sort the database alphabetically, will the search become faster???

Comment: Relational databases like SQL Server CE **don't have** a permanent ordering per se. The data as such doesn't have an order - only when you query it and use `ORDER BY` there is any ordering guaranteed. So in short: you **CANNOT** permanently sort your data - you will need to use `ORDER BY` on your queries. You might speed that query up by defining an **index** on the `English` column

Answer (score 2):

> But it just shows as i queried. It doesn't effect permanently on database. What i want is that i want to sort the database permanently. How can i do that???

For this, you have to update the database with your query result. The link below will enlighten the solution.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/can-the-sorting-from-an-order-by-statement-be-saved-explicitly-with-only-one-upd

> Another question: i have about 70,000 rows and when i perform a search query in my windows app the searching result is very slow. If i sort the database alphabetically,will the search become faster???

I don't really think it will speed the search speed. Even then, it depends on your search query to some extend. I found the article which is very much interesting and should be helpful to you. Please check this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34372/Top-10-steps-to-optimize-data-access-in-SQL-Server

Hope I have answered your questions.